# Can I do something while splash is being showed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Please tell me can I use a time while application is loading (while splash screen is being showed) to perform some background operations? (I need to call CLLocationManager and update current location) If I'm allowed to do it please tell me where to put a code.

Comment: The "splash screen" wasn't really intended to be used as a splash screen. It was originally there to display your UI of your app, but without any data in it. This was to be displayed immediately to give the user the impression that the app has loaded really quickly and then refreshed with the data in it. But people tweaked it to display a loading screen (company logo, etc) so I think Apple ended up just accepting that was what was going to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to perform anything while real splash screen is shown. 
Your actions starts in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

method which is executed when splash screen removed.
If you want to perform some time-cost operation before showing user interface, your only options is show manually "fake" splash screen during this time. It can be image or anything else e.g. activity indicator or animation. If you use same image that used for splash screen,
user will see no difference, it will look like splash screen will remain some seconds longer for him, but you will already have your data loaded.

In this case your app delegate may be like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] 
    initWithNibName:@"FakeSplashViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self performSelectorInBackground: @selector(someLongOperation) withObject: nil];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void) someLongOperation{
    //doing something
    //...
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(atLastLoadGUI) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

- (void) atLastLoadGUI{
    // start GUI
}
```